# iPhone storage shows 57+GB used... where is it?

Tags: iphone, storage

[image]

This screenshot shows that there is 57+GB used on my iPhone.

However looking through the list and adding up the values comes to a maximum of 10GB (and that's an overestimation).

So, where is the other 40+ GB?

I have been deleting apps recently to try and clear space but every couple days it tells me the iPhone is running low on storage.

I feel like this is some sort of bug or something because I really don't know where the rest of the space is?

Comment: @JaimeSantaCruz true it may be a duplicate but it appears that question doesn't have an accepted answer.

Comment: The answer is probably there, it's just that the OP didn't bother to accept one or, if they didn't find one of the answers acceptable, ask follow-up questions.

Comment: @fsb the likelihood of getting any response beyond "why did you revive this old, out of date question" is very low when adding comments to a 3-year-old question. As it turns out the last paragraph of the lowest voted question is 1. still relevant and 2. what I actually did. But hardly useful. Oh well.

Comment: You have the option to add a bounty to that question.  For this site, that's how you get attention to questions with no accepted answers.  I would recommend you look into that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't find it from Storage Manager, I think it's some kinds of bugs or lags.

Have you tried to reset the settings? Sometimes, it might help.

Comment: I've been thinking of backing it up and doing a factory reset. Just worried that this erroneous data might also be backed up. Haha! Thanks, will give that a go today.

Comment: OK, that seems to have worked. Thanks. I now have 54GB of free space :D Just to note. I did the "Erase all content and reset settings".